# What is the CPU load unit of measure in cgroup (difference between CPU Usage and CPU Load)?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cadvisor

In my Kubernetes installation, I can see cAdvisor reports a measurement called "container_cpu_load_average_10s" for each pod/container. I get values such as 232, 6512 and so on.

So, what is the unit of measure for CPU load here? To me "CPU Load" and "CPU Usage" are used interchangeably, so I can't understand why its not a value between [0-100] ?

**UPDATE**:

Here I put the related line from cAdvisor log:

```
...
container_cpu_load_average_10s{container_name="",id="/system.slice/kubelet.service",image="",name="",namespace="",pod_name=""} 1598
...
```

Comment: Please consider add a comment before downvoting :(

Comment: Please provide the log file.

Comment: @Akar Done. See the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the number of tasks. A very nice explanation can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/667078/high-cpu-utilization-but-low-load-average